# Is it possible to curb moderator abuse?

Tags: discussion

If one has a confrontation with a moderator whose actions seem to be capricious and baselessly retaliatory, what's the procedure required to lodge a complaint?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/222992)

Answer (score 15):

Before you file a formal complaint with SE, you should get a sense what the community thinks about the issue by asking about it here.  In the past, you've complained about similar things, but the community felt your complaints weren't justified.  Seeing such a reaction should make you stop and think that maybe the problem is on your end, not with a particular moderator.

In general, my impression is that you go out of your way to be contrary, pick fights with people, push the limits of what you are allowed to do here, then try to defend yourself by arguing the letter of the law.  The presumption of rightness will be with the moderators until you can make a good case otherwise.  If you can't convince your peers, then you don't have a case.

Comment: Thanks for your input,  but what I was asking for was a procedure, which Dave Tweed graciously provided.

Comment: @EMFi: I did give you a procedure, which is to ask here first.

Comment: That wasn't really a procedure, which would have been like: "Here's how you do it", it was more like: "Here's what I want you to do.", followed by some thinly veiled "advice" seemingly designed to foment discord.

Comment: Note that the link I provided says essentially the same thing that Olin is saying.

Comment: So you're a team of bullies which want me to kow-tow to your  edicts, be they wrong or not?

Comment: @EMFi: This is what I mean about picking fights.  I really don't see how suggesting to run your grievance past ALL users here by discussing it on meta makes us a "team of bullies", unless you consider all users here to be the bullies.  In that case you should seriously ask yourself why your interpretation disagrees with everyone else's.  Meta is a fairly democratic place.  Everyone gets just one vote, even mods.  If a good number of uses vote and the consensus is solidly in one direction, you should take it seriously.  You also assume everyone will disagree with you, which you can't know.

Comment: My comment about bullies was directed at Dave, but I didn't address it to him; Mea culpa.  In any case, without the tag it should have been interpreted as directed to you, not the entire group. Had I meant it to be directed to the group I would have stated so explicitly, so your attempt to put words in my mouth was disingenuous, as were the nonsensical "logical consequences" you drew from your false premise.

Answer (score 5):

To convert Dave Tweed's comment into an answer:

The StackExchange Meta has [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges) with a good [Community Wiki Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28869/249305) covering the process and structure for working with moderators.